# Simplifying fractions containing multiple variables.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Write as a single fraction:

$(4x+2y)/(3x) - (5x+9y)/(6x)   +  4$

Simplify your answer as much as possible.

The answer that I got from when I did the math was: (27x-5y)/(6x). But I have asked some of my friends who some got a different answer from mine. Please let me know if this seems right, and if it isn't please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your expression is ambiguous.  Surround numerators and denominators with parentheses.  For example, do you mean $\frac{4x + 2y}{3x}$ or $4x + \frac{2y}{3x}$ in the first term??

Comment: I just fixed it. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Actually, I am wondering if you mean $(4x+2y)/(3x) - (5x+9y)/(6x) + 4 = \dfrac{4x+2y}{3x} - \dfrac{5x+9y}{6x} + 4$.  Note the difference from what you wrote?

Comment: The way you wrote it in the first part from your first comment was how I meant to write it. Once again, I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The way how you wrote it in your second comment is how the question is supposed to look like.

Comment: I edited your post to reflect this.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much but does my answer look correct in your opinion?

Comment: What are the steps that you have taken to get your answer?

Comment: I just edited my answer as I got a new one. I first got (81x^2 - 15xy)/(18x^2) and then I canceled out both of the exponents giving me (81x - 15xy)/(18x). My next step in simplifying it was to divide everything by 3 which gave me my new final answer of (27x-5y)/(6x).

Comment: If your friends got $\frac 92 - \frac {5y}{6x}$ I'd say that is *also* a correct answer.  But *both* are correct.  I'm not sure I see any other acceptable answers though.

Answer (score 1):

your answer is right, don't believe the others.

Comment: So my answer of (27x-5y)/(6x) is correct. Right?

Comment: @UptownBongo9454 Based on the current text in your question, I also got the same answer as you.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Ok. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Put them over a common denominator:

$\frac {4x+2y}{3x}\cdot \frac 22 - \frac {5x + 9y}{6x} + 4\cdot\frac {6x}{6x}=$

$\frac {2(4x+2y) - (5x+9y) +4\cdot 6x}{6x}=$

$\frac {(8x+4y) -(5x +9y) + 24x}{6x}=\frac {(8x-5x+24x)+(4y-9y)}{6x}=$

$\frac {27x -5y}{6x}$

Now the sentence "Simplify your answer as much as possible" might be subjective.

*Many* mathematicians would say, that's it.  We have a single fraction.  That's a s simple as it gets.

Some might say the sum in the numerator can be separated.

$\frac {27x - 5y}{6x} = \frac {27x}{6x} - \frac {5y}{6x} = \frac 92 - \frac {5y}{6x}$.

Which is "simpler"?

I'm not sure.  I'd say a single rational expression rather than a sum in rational expressions is simpler and I'd go with your original answer is the simplest.

But $\frac {27x - 5y}{6x}$ and $\frac 92-\frac {5y}{6x}$ both equal the same thing.